# Transparent context menu on tap-and-hold with React Native?

Tags: react-native

I would like to create something like a context menu for an entry within a [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist): If the user taps and holds, a central dot appears and a couple of icons or SVG graphics around that dot. When the user moves the finger towards one of the icons (and releases the tap), the respective action is triggered, see the screenshot which illustrates that:

[image: iss]

Is there an out-of-the-box component for that? Setting up a [modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal) looks overkill, but are there other alternatives?

Comment: hmm i would use something like this https://github.com/mastermoo/react-native-action-button  you can put icon on the end of flatitem and it could be transparent with specific height and width and if user will click on it put there that flat buttons from that library but i guess you will have to fork it and stlyle it to your case ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this specially for you: https://snack.expo.io/@alexandrelage/4774e0

It's a boilerplate. There is work to do.
I just don't believe the user should need to drag their finger through the menu items in order to select one option. It sounds anti-accessibility design. Instead, you'd better expect the user to select the menu item normally with good old `onPress` prop.

#### 1. The `render()` method looks like this:

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          scrollEnabled={!this.state.selectedItem}
        />
        {this.state.selectedItem && this.menu()}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

1. There is a `FlatList` component which disables scrolling when there
   is some `selectedItem` defined on state.
2. There is a `menu` component which is only rendered when there is some `selectedItem` defined on state. This `menu` will have the menu items with their actions.

#### 2. The `renderItem` method looks like this:

```js
  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={item}
      style={styles.item}
      onLongPress={event => this.handleLongPress(item, event)}>
      <Text>Long press list item</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

It calls `handleLongPress` method when the user presses the item on FlatList. The `handleLongPress` sets the `selectedItem` and the `pageX` and `pageY` on state.

```js
  handleLongPress = (item, event) => {
    this.animateMenuScale();
    const locationY = event.nativeEvent.pageY;
    const locationX = event.nativeEvent.pageX;
    this.setState({ selectedItem: { item, locationY, locationX } });
  };
```

This `setState` will trigger rendering the `menu` component as follows.

#### 3. The `menu` component looks like this:

```js
  menu = () => {
    const { selectedItem } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.menuBackground}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.menu,
            {
              top: selectedItem.locationY-MENU_RADIUS_END/2,
              left: selectedItem.locationX-MENU_RADIUS_END/2,
              width: this.menuScale,
              height: this.menuScale,
              borderRadius: this.menuScale
            },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

1. This component is Animated when rendered. It uses `this.menuScale` as value for its `width` and `height`. `this.menuScale` starts animating (growing) when the uses presses the item (`handleLongPress`).
2. This component's position is set to `absolute`, so it is easy to use absolute values for `top` and `left` props.

#### 4. Finally `setTimeout` to clear the `selectedItem` state:

This line on `shouldComponentUpdate` sets a timeout if the `selectedItem` state exists. This timeout waits for 5 seconds then clears the `selectedItem` state.

```js
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    nextState.selectedItem &&
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({ selectedItem: null }), 5000); //Clear after few seconds
    return true;
  }
```

I hope it helps.

**TODO:**

- Add haptics feedback (vibrator).
- Add menu items.

Comment: @B--rian nice :D I just updated my answer with few comments. You're welcome. I hope you enjoy.